# Вычитание значений, находящихся в одном столбце таблицы КликХауса

Tags: clickhouse

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли в КликХаусе функционал для вычитания дат/чисел в одном столбце? То есть, значения вычитаются в построчном порядке.

**Например, имея таблицу вида:**

```
| Год  |
|------|
|2000  | 
|2005  | 
|2010  | 
|2020  |
```

**Получить таблицу такого вида:**

```
| Год  | Разница |
|------|---------|
|2000  |    0    |
|2005  |    5    |
|2020  |    15   |
|2050  |    30   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно существует. Во-первых можно использовать функцию `neighbor`:

```
create table default.test(val UInt32) engine=MergeTree() ORDER BY val;

insert into default.test values (2000),(2005),(2010),(2020);

select val, val-neighbor(val, -1) from default.test;
```

Ещё есть `LAG()`, `LEAD()`.